# how to categorize data on one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I am building an app that has language model, a question model, and an answer model.  I would like to display lists of questions and answers on one "My Questions" index view page into the following categories:

1. My Unanswered Questions (meaning only the questions belonging to current user)
2. My Answered Questions (meaning only the questions belonging to current user)
3. Questions I Answered (meaning only the answers belonging to current user)

I am new to programming and I'm not sure if researching the word "categories" in Rails was the right term for this, but I wasn't able to find any helpful information this way.  Any insight would be much appreciated!

Here are my routes:

```
Languagecheck::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :languages do
    resources :questions, except: [:index] do 
      resources :answers
    end
   end

  resources :questions, only: [:index, :new, :create]

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
  root to: 'welcome#index' 
  end
```

Here is my question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'obscenity/active_model'
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy=>true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language

  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }


  validates :body, obscenity: true
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 160 }, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true

end
```

Here is my answer model:

```
  class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'obscenity/active_model'
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user

 validates :name, obscenity: true
 validates :body, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 160 }, presence: true

end
```

My user model is set up where the user has many questions and answers.

Here is my questions controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_language, except: [:index]
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @questions = current_user.questions
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    authorize @question
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    authorize @question
  end

  def update
     @question = Question.find(params[:id])
     authorize @question

     if @question.update_attributes(question_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Question was updated."
       redirect_to [@language, @question]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the question. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end

  def create
     @question = Question.new(question_params)
     @question.language = @language
     @question.user = current_user
     authorize @question

     if @question.save
       flash[:notice] = "Question was saved."
       redirect_to [@language, @question]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the question. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end
  def destroy
    @question.destroy.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:id, :body)

    end

    def set_language
      @language = Language.find(params[:language_id])
    end

end
```

Here is my answers controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_language_and_question
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @answers = Answer.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    @answer.question = @question
    @answer.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@language, @question], notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @answer }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to [@language, @question], error: 'Answer was  not successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.update(answer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: 'Answer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @answer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to answers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_answer
      @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
      @answer ||= @question.answers.new
    end

     def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:id, :body)
    end

    def set_language_and_question
      @language = Language.find(params[:language_id])
      @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
end
```

And here is the "My Questions" view (which is just listing all questions at the moment):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>My Unanswered Questions</h3>
      <% @questions.each do |question| %>
         <div class="media">
           <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">
      <p><%= question.language ? link_to(question.body, [question.language, question]) : question.body %></p>
            </h4>
            <small>
               submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago by <%= question.user.name %> <br/>
               <%= question.answers.count %> Answers
             </small>
           </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= link_to "Ask a New Question", new_question_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>My Answered Questions</h3>
      <% @questions.each do |question| %>
         <div class="media">
           <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">
      <p><%= question.language ? link_to(question.body, [question.language, question]) : question.body %></p>
            </h4>
            <small>
               submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago by <%= question.user.name %> <br/>
               <%= question.answers.count %> Answers
             </small>
           </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>
       </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>Questions I Answered</h3>
      <% @questions.each do |question| %>
         <div class="media">
           <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">
      <p><%= question.language ? link_to(question.body, [question.language, question]) : question.body %></p>
            </h4>
            <small>
               submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago by <%= question.user.name %> <br/>
               <%= question.answers.count %> Answers
             </small>
           </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're referring to by categories, but would it be enough to add 3 scopes to your Question model (one for each of the three cases you mention), use them to populate 3 instance variables in your `QuestionsController#index` and then use those in your template?

Comment: They are saying group them by unanswered/answered/I answered, 3 categories. I'm thinking either have 2 sub-types of question (answered/unanswered), and a second type that is answer. Either that, or two types: question/answer, with question having an answered boolean that you use group_by on.

Answer (score 0):

Valerie,

Like Matt, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "categorize". It sounds like you want to be able to loop through a variety of question groups on a given page. So something like this:

```
<% @user.unanswered_questions.each do |question| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<% @user.answered_questions.each do |question| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<% @user.answers.each do |answer| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

On a single view.

If that is what you mean, then Matt's suggestion sounds like the right one. You just need to create scopes or methods on question.rb to serve that purpose. I'd actually create the below scopes on question:

```
scope :answered, ->   { joins(:answers) }
scope :unanswered, -> { where.not(id: joins(:answers).pluck(:id)) }
```

You'd then be able to do `@user.questions.answered` and `@user.questions.unanswered` (slightly different from the above, but either is an option). That second one is a little bit complicated. Basically, we're getting the questions with answers (`joins(:answers)`), taking their ids (`pluck(:id)`), and then grabbing all the questions with ids NOT in that collection (ie, the ones without answers). I **think** that'd work, but I haven't tested that out. For more info, check out the AR docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Is that what you mean? Generally in Rails, with questions like this that involve segmenting (or categorizing) data, you want to think about pushing this functionality down to the model layer, where it's most abstract.

Also note that these scopes might as well be class methods. There's not really any great difference, as long as they return AR relations, so they can be "chained".